# Changing Timezone, Centos Apache server

Tags: centos, ssh, timezone

I'm trying to change my server's timezone.

I was following [this](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-change-setup-timezone-tz-variable/) tutorial but I can't get it to change to Pacific Standard Time.

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/EST localtime
```

Will work, but

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/PST localtime
```

will not.  What's going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to do two things: edit /etc/sysconfig/clock, you will need to change the ZONE variable. And once you've changed it, next time you reboot your CentOS it will apply the change.

To apply it inmediately you need to change the /etc/localtime, i.e.

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/PST8PDT /etc/localtime
```

That will make the change immediate, but remember to also edit /etc/sysconfig/clock so your change won't be undone in next reboot.

Answer (score 2):

```
# yum -y install system-config-date
# system-config-date
```

Comment: This only works on systems that have a GUI.

Comment: Hmm, you are right. I distinctly remember a curses version of this. Looks like it is gone now.http://fadvisor.net/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/06/timeconfig.png

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me on CentOS 5. All other means of altering the settings didn't make date use the correct time zone (UTC). Now if only I can get hwclock to sync (--systohc isn't doing the job)

Answer (score 2):

From CentOS7 onwards:

```
timedatectl set-timezone US/Pacific
```

*The question doesn't specify CentOS version, and there is no /etc/sysconfig/clock anymore on a default CentOS 7 (RHEL 7).*

Answer (score 1):

Try `ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Pacific localtime`